# how to combine SQL queries in columns

Tags: sql

I need rows of result set into columns. I currently have written the query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Male FROM add_faculty_override
WHERE gender='Male'
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Female FROM add_faculty_override
WHERE gender='Female';
```

This gives me the result as :

```
male
3          //total number of males
5          //total number of females
```

What I'd like to have instead as the result set is :

```
male   female
3        5
```

Comment: What RDBMS, A Pivot could be used in conjunction with a simple group by.

Comment: @xQbert PIVOT is not needed here. Its quite simple without a PIVOT. PIVOT would just be an overkill

Comment: My Queston has been answerd by Goat CO

Comment: @user3821879 Good, so please mark his answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN gender='Male' THEN 1 END) AS Male
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN gender='Female' THEN 1 END) AS Female
FROM add_faculty_override
```

If you don't really need both results on one row then you can simply `GROUP`:

```
SELECT Gender, COUNT(*) AS Gender_Count
FROM add_faculty_override
GROUP BY Gender
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works to me so i can use this again?

Comment: @user3821879 Sure thing, the `CASE` statement returns either `1` or `NULL` depending on the criteria (`NULL` is the default when a row doesn't meet any `WHERE` criteria in a `CASE` statement and no `ELSE` is specified), `COUNT()` (like all aggregate functions) ignores `NULL` values, so it's left counting up all occurrences where `gender='Male'` for the first one, and `gender='Female'` for the second. I refer to it as a conditional aggregate, since you're only aggregating items that meet certain criteria.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
SELECT (SELECT     COUNT(gender)
        FROM       add_faculty_override
        WHERE      gender='Male') AS 'Male',

       (SELECT     COUNT(gender) 
        FROM       add_faculty_override
        WHERE      gender='Female') AS 'Female'
```

You can see this here->http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ed9d/1

Hope this helps!!!